# Query with structured data on the HERE API suggest endpoint

Tags: here-api

I am currently developing an auto-suggest adress-input form. The flow will be quite classical, so consumers enters first the postal code and get suggestion of the city connected to the postal code which will be inserted into a second input field

After this the consumer should enter the street into a third field.

By this I have country, postalcode and city as seperate values. Is there any way of sending those data points as structured data into the suggest API?

Querying for Germany+Berlin+10405+P results in the correct suggestions of streets starting with P in the postalcode area 10405 but also contains one entry for a completly wrong postal code area:

```
"address": {
                "country": "Germany",
                "state": "Berlin",
                "county": "Berlin",
                "city": "Berlin",
                "district": "Kreuzberg",
                "street": "Puttkamerstraße",
                "postalCode": "10969"
            },
```

Comment: Do you mean next stage of suggestion, like street name while you send postcode? all these fields are in different fields so send json to the server instead of string.

Comment: based on the API documentation there is only one single query inut and not seperated fields :(

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder API will list all possible combination for the search text present in search critera. Hence it is returning Puttkamerstraße, by ignoring 10969. You can apply filtering the result criteria while rendering though.